# UITableView to fill the screen [Swift]

Tags: swift, tableview

How can I make it so that the a UITableView at the bottom of a screen can fill the whole screen once you start scrolling. I tried placing it in a scrollView but it doesn't seem to work. (sorry if it's a stupid question but I'm new to swift)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: UITableView inherits from UIScollView.So do not include UITableView in UIScollView. You need to constrain it to the bottom edge of its parent-view. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: @Dris ?? I'm not asking for any code, I'm building an app with a table view that's taking a certain part of the screen at the bottom and I want that small part to get expanded to the whole screen once you start scrolling in it

Comment: @mahan I tried constraining it from the bottom only but the view above it got blocked by the tableview. I'm trying to make the whole screen view move up

Answer (score 0):

So I guess what you are trying to do is you want to expand your table view in an upward direction as the user starts scrolling.

Since you haven't shared any UI/code with us, giving any solution is hard. But I can suggest you something.
You can pin your table view at the bottom by giving leading, trailing and bottom as 0 or whatever you want.
Then add top constraint >= 0 (or the final space you want).
Then add an initial height constraint say 50 (your minimum) and make an outlet of constraint.
Now table view already as a scrollView, you just need to use delegate scrollViewDidScroll.
In the delegate, you need to get the current  content offset and add that offset to your height constraint before adding check if the value is less than the maximum height you want (view height - 50 or whatever)

Something like this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollOffSet = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let finalHeight = scrollOffSet + tableHeightConstraint.constant
    guard finalOffset <= (view.frame.height + 50) else { return }
    tableHeightConstraint.constant = finalHeight
}
```